# gcc - linker error that makes no sense

Tags: gcc, ld, undefined-reference

Using the [Makefile](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/blob/master/Makefile) provided by the Pi GPIO library, I made the libpigpio.so shard object using:

```
# from line 119 in make file
make libpigpio.so
```

The shared object is created fine.  The Makefile first created the `pigpio.o` object, then the `command.o` object, and links them together as a shared object.  So far so good!

I wrote a very small main function that calls the `gpioInitialise` and `gpioGetPWMfrequency`.

It doesn't really matter which functions, what's important is they are defined in `pigpio.h` and written in `pigpio.c`.

Meaning the shared object **should** have them.

The compile command for my code is:

```
 gcc -Wall -pthread -fpic -L. -lpigpio -o drive drive.c
```

Still I get the undefined reference error to both those functions.

It makes no sense! If it didn't find the shared object, it would reject the command.  I also tried it `-l:libpigpio.so` and still the same problem.

I am compiling directly on the Rpi A+ (not using a cross compiler).  So it should work!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a link order question. Please try the flowing command.

`gcc drive.c -Wall -pthread -fpic -o drive -L. -lpigpio`

you can read [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc) for more details.